# Prove that $CP^1 \cong S^2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-topology, projective-space

I'm self learning Algebraic topology from Rotman's Introduction to Algebraic Topology and I've come across this problem:

> Prove that $CP^1 \cong S^2$

I'm really struggling with showing this.

I know that $CP^1 = \{[(z_1,z_2)] : (z_1, z_2) \in \Bbb C^2 \text{ and }  (z_1, z_2) = \lambda (z_3, z_4) \text{ for some $\lambda$ in $\Bbb C - \{0\}$} $
which is the set of lines in $4$-space through the origin.

I get the feeling I'd have to somehow show a mapping from the upper hemisphere to the whole sphere, but from here I have no idea how to proceed.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Hint : stereographic projection.

Comment: Here is an alternative way. What are elements of $S^2$ and how do you define a map from $S^2$ to $CP^1$ by charts? Then glue the chart morphism properly and show the map is homeo.

Comment: @N.H. Could you elaborate?  I'm not seeing how $S^n - \{N\} \cong R^n$ will help.

Comment: It's easy to see that $CP^1$ is the one-point compactification of $CP^1 \backslash [1:0] \cong \Bbb C$ so this implies that $CP^1 \cong S^2$ as they are both the Alexandrov compactification of $\Bbb C$.

Comment: What does the notation $CP^1 \backslash [1:0]$ mean?